# What is the difference between Silhouette and Deadbolt 2 in Play Framework

Tags: scala, playframework, deadbolt-2, silhouette

We have two famous plugin for authentication and authorization in Play Framework, [Silhouette](https://github.com/mohiva/play-silhouette) and [Deadbolt 2](https://github.com/schaloner/deadbolt-2). My question is What is the difference between these two plugin? and for what situation we should use Silhouette or Deadbolt 2?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Deadbolt 2 is only an authorization framework. Silhouette is an authentication framework which supports also a basic authorization mechanism.

If you need authentication (web form, social, two factor, basic auth, ...) then you need Silhouette.

If you need authorization (manage access to your actions) then you need either Deadbolt 2 or Silhouette. Where Deadbolt 2 is the more powerful one in the authorization area.

Comment: Can they not be combined?

Comment: @akkie given that this answer is almost 2 years old, is there any reference implementation on combining Silhouette authentication with Deadbolt authorization?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not aware of an example